# The set of all finite subsets of $\mathbb{Z}_+$ is countable. Is my proof correct?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

**Question**

> **Prove:** The set of all finite subsets of $\mathbb{Z}_+$ is countable

I assume the following results:

- A countable union of countable sets is countable.
- A finite cartesian product of countable sets is countable.
- If for any set $A$ there is a bijective correspondence with some countable set $B$, then $A$ is countable.

**Attempt**

This is my attempted proof of the statement:

> *Proof*
>
> Let $J$ denote the set of all finite subsets of $\mathbb{Z}_+$. Then $J = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{Z}_+} J_n$, where $J_n$ is the set of all subsets of $\mathbb{Z}_+$ with $n$ elements. We prove that $J_n$ is countable by showing that for any $n \in \mathbb{Z}_+$ there exists a bijective function $f : \mathbb{Z}_+^n \rightarrow J_n$ such that for any tuple $(k_1,k_2,...,k_n) \in \mathbb{Z}_+^n$, the following conditions hold:
>
> 1. The set $f(k_1, k_2,...,k_n)$ contains $n$ elements
> 2. The largest element in $f(k_1,k_2,...,k_n)$ is $\sum_{i=1}^nk_i$.
>
> We use induction. Base case $n = 1$ is trivial, since we can define a function $f(n) = \{n\}$, which is clearly bijective and satisfies the above conditions. Thus, assume that the result holds for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}_+$. Hence, there exists $f_k: \mathbb{Z}^k_+ \rightarrow J_k$ which is a bijection satisfying the above properties. To show that the result holds for $k+1$, define $f : \mathbb{Z}_+^{k+1} \rightarrow J_{k+1}$ as follows:
> \begin{align*}
>     f(n_1,n_2,...,n_{k+1}) = f_k(n_1,...n_k) \cup \{n_1+n_2+n_3+...+n_{k+1}\}
> \end{align*}
> By the inductive hypothesis, the set $f_k(n_1,...,n_k)$ contains $k$ distinct elements and the largest element is $\sum_{i=1}^{k}n_i$. Thus, since:
> \begin{align*}
>     \sum_{i=1}^{k}n_i < \sum_{i=1}^{k+1}n_i
> \end{align*}
> it follows that $f$ satisfies conditions (1) and (2). Then since $f_k$ is bijective and the last element in $f(n_1,...,n_{k+1})$ is not in $f_k(n_1,...,n_k)$, the bijectivity of $f$ follows. Hence, the result holds for $k+1$. Thus, since $\mathbb{Z}_+^n$ is countable and there exists a bijection $f : \mathbb{Z}_+^n \rightarrow J_n$, it follows that $J_n$ is countable for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}_+$.
>
> Therefore, since $J_n$ is countable, we conclude that $J = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{Z}_+} J_n $ is countable $\space \Box$

Is this proof correct? If so, how can I improve it? Thank you!

Comment: That's an ingenious construction and your proof is fine. There is another approach based on binary representations that might be of interest to you. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hereditarily_finite_set.